# Error : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'db.transaction') in ReactNative

Tags: ios, sqlite, react-native

I am following all the instructions for populating value from existing database for iOS from this  :[link](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)

And Using Following Code:

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
var db; 
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
errorCB(err) {
  console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
};

successCB() {
  console.log("SQL executed fine");
};

openCB() {
  console.log("Database OPENED");
};

openDB() {
db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "sqliteexample", createFromLocation : 1}, this.openCB, this.errorCB);

}

populateDB() {
  db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Users", [], (tx, results) => {
        console.log("Query completed");

        // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.

        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log('len' + len)
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          let row = results.rows.item(i);
          console.log(`User: ${row}`);
        }
      });
  });
}

render() {
    return (
<View style={styles.container} >
<Button onPress={this. openDB}
         title="open Database"
         color="#841584"/>
<Button onPress={this. populateDB}
         title="Get Data"
         color="#841584"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this Error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'db.transaction')

But Successfully open database getting following message in console:

> 2018-06-08 11:43:40.678
>   [info][tid:com.facebook.react.SQLiteQueue][SQLite.m:255] open cb
>   finished ok 2018-06-08 11:43:40.679
>   [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] DB opened: sqliteexample
>   2018-06-08 11:43:40.679165+0530 FlatListAppDemo[1018:61832] open cb
>   finished ok 2018-06-08 11:43:40.679220+0530
>   FlatListAppDemo[1018:61820] DB opened: sqliteexample

Please Help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
var database_name = "sqliteexample"; // Add your Database name
var database_version = "1.0"; // Add your Database Version
var database_size = 200000; // Add your Database Size
var database_displayname = "SQL Database"; // Add your Database Displayname
var db; 

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
errorCB(err) {
  console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
};

successCB() {
  console.log("SQL executed fine");
};

openCB() {
  console.log("Database OPENED");
};

openDB() {

 db = SQLite.openDatabase(database_name, database_version, database_displayname, database_size, this.openCB, this.errorCB);

}

populateDB() {

  db = SQLite.openDatabase(database_name, database_version, database_displayname, database_size, this.openCB, this.errorCB);
  db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Users", [], (tx, results) => {
        console.log("Query completed");

        // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.

        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log('len' + len)
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          let row = results.rows.item(i);
          console.log(`User: ${row}`);
        }
      });
  });
}

render() {
    return (
<View style={styles.container} >
<Button onPress={this. openDB}
         title="open Database"
         color="#841584"/>
<Button onPress={this. populateDB}
         title="Get Data"
         color="#841584"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: problem is not there in open database, error occured when populateDB is called and it shows this : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'db.transaction')

Comment: the db variable did not have the database reference that's why the error is occured

Comment: so, what's the solution?? your Updated answer is also throwing same error..

Comment: db reference is not set correctly in variable db that's why  'db.transaction' error happening

Comment: Are you sure the db name is 'sqliteexample'  correct ?

Comment: sir,If my db name is incorrect then why I am getting success message i.e DB opened: sqliteexample on database open in my log??

Comment: now I am getting this error..Error handler not provided: ', { message: 'no such table: Users', code: 5 }

Comment: There is no table Users in SQL.sqlite. Please check your database

Comment: Can you show me. Where did you create your DB and Tables ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172755/discussion-between-divya-thakkar-and-prabhu).

Answer (score 0):

so I think it could be just timing issue. The safest way to obtain a database object would be inside the success callback which will receive a valid db object if all goes well in openDatabase. so change your code to this and try it...

```
openCB(myDB) {
  console.log("Database OPENED");
  db = myDB;
};

openDB() {
  SQLite.openDatabase({name : "sqliteexample", createFromLocation : 1}, this.openCB, this.errorCB);

}
```